# How to rewrite to get rid of the subquery in the select-clause

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

```
Select
Xyz,
CASE
    WHEN 'AEJ-DODGE-AC-'
      ||measure IN
      (SELECT child
      FROM interim_dim_measures_mas
      WHERE child LIKE 'AEJ-DODGE-AC%'
        CONNECT BY prior child = parent
        START WITH parent      = 'Total Revenue (GBS).1'
      )
    THEN -1*CAST(datavalue AS FLOAT)
    ELSE CAST(datavalue AS FLOAT)
  END AS amount
FROM interim_data_misbaej,
  w_csrbrd
WHERE LENGTH(period) = 3
AND 'AEJ-BK-'
  || book = region_book(+)
```

Comment: This is a very unusual syntax. What are you trying to accomplish with the || construction? Also, why is it a problem that there is a subquery? Finally, does your existing query actually work right now?

Comment: That '||' part is not important; the problem of the subquery being executed 500 million times and kill the performance; the table interim_data_misbaej has 4.5million rows and w_csrbrd has 5000 rows; so would like to know equivalent sql that has that subquery removed from the select-clause

Comment: Okay, I figured out this is an Oracle question, which I'm not qualified to be very helpful with. But I did fix the tags so maybe someone else will pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to force this to run just once, and GROUP BY with COUNT to determine if a match had been found:

```
Select Xyz, 
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(m.child) THEN -1*CAST(datavalue AS FLOAT)
         ELSE CAST(datavalue AS FLOAT)
       END AS amount
FROM interim_data_misbaej, w_csrbrd
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT child
  FROM interim_dim_measures_mas
  WHERE child LIKE 'AEJ-DODGE-AC%'
    CONNECT BY prior child = parent
    START WITH parent      = 'Total Revenue (GBS).1'
  ) m ON ('AEJ-DODGE-AC-' || measure) = m.child
WHERE LENGTH(period) = 3
  AND 'AEJ-BK-' || book = region_book(+)
GROUP BY Xyz, measure, datavalue
```